# TSQL PIVOT Part of COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table but unsure of whether it is possible to pivot some of the columns from the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #test ( id int, Area varchar(10), [grouping] varchar(15), task_1 int, task_2 int)

INSERT INTO #test Values (10,'A','HighNeeds',1, 10)
INSERT INTO #test Values (10,'B','HighNeeds',1, 12)
INSERT INTO #test Values (12,'C','Non HighNeeds',2, 14)

select * from #test
-------------------------------------------------
id  Area    grouping        task_1  task_2
10  A       HighNeeds       1       10
10  B       HighNeeds       1       12
12  C       Non HighNeeds   2       14

What I'm trying to get is:
-------------------------------------------------
id  Area    Tasks      HighNeeds   Non HighNeeds   
10  A       task_1     1           NULL
10  A       task_2     10          NULL
10  B       task_1     1           NULL
10  B       task_2     12          NULL
12  C       task_1     NULL        2
12  C       takk_2     NULL        14
```

Basically I'm trying to keep the `ID` and `Area` columns, but pivoting grouping data and tasks columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite tricky - you need to pivot `Grouping` as columns and unpivot `task_1` and `task_2` as row values:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id, Area, grouping, tskCount, Task
    FROM 
        test
    UNPIVOT 
    (
       tskCount
       for Task in (task_1, task_2)
    ) unpvt
) X
PIVOT
(
 SUM(tskCount)
 for grouping in (HighNeeds, [Non HighNeeds])
)pvt;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83278/3)

Comment: I'm still new to SQL pivoting, need some times to understand your code, but it just works!!! You are amazing！ Thanks!